# leads and custom object

Tags: leads, lead-conversion, professional-edition

I have a custom object spaces. in the lead I get to choose many spaces(via lookup who has interest in spaces) but in the spaces object there are also different leads which are interested in one space. when the account is ready to be converted, I need to clear all the prospect leads in the space related list and make the spaces I chose in the leads object related to the lead. what approach can I do? im in the professional edition so no workflows and triggrs please. respect post

Comment: do you want filter the lookup records?

Comment: no, what I need is that when a lead is converted, the other lead in the space object will be removed and the converted lead will be related to the spaces.

Comment: YOu need a trigger for this. When the lead is converted check that if there is another lead is present or not related to the spaces. If yes then delete/ remove that record else do nothing